# How can I automatically open a website (or some other text showing entitiy) with the result of this Lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have the following lambda function in nodesj16.x:

```
function getScore(arr) {
let temp;
let i = Math.floor((Math.random() \* arr.length));
temp = arr\[i\];
console.log(i);
console.log(temp);
return temp;
}

 
const arrScores = \[700, 820, 640, 460, 726, 850, 694, 721, 556\];

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) =\> {
let creditScore = getScore(arrScores);
callback(null, "Credit score pulled is: " + creditScore + ".");

};
```

An execution result looks like this:

Response:
"Credit score pulled is: 556."

I would like to automatically show the result after the lambda gets executed - I don't care if a browser opens or whatever. Can someone help me?

I'm a total newbie, so I've just googled around with questions like "lambda node.js write response in browser" ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need example of calling AWS Lambda from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038180/need-example-of-calling-aws-lambda-from-javascript)

Comment: A lambda cannot open anything, a lambda returns something to the caller and is done. If you want to display the response that is the responsibility of the caller, your CLI, your website, your desktop application, ...